# What is causing OpenGL 2.0 based shader handling code to crash in ::glBegin()?

Tags: opengl, segmentation-fault, glsl, shader

For what it's worth:

- my graphics drivers (ATI Mobility Radeon 4570) are up to date.
- I have managed to get ARB extensions based shader handling code working on the same config previously (although it's been a while before I came back to shaders).
- I was following the Lighthouse3d tutorials in my setup (...loosely: [Lighthouse3d shader setup](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/setup-for-glsl-example/) the shader compile log code had been ripped from a SO question, sorry about the lack of credit, I can't seem to find it now)

Basically, all my OpenGL operations seem to execute successfully; the shaders compile and the program links. As you can see below, I have ended up checking OpenGL errors after each one of the gl*** calls. The shaders themselves are trivial.

Then again, of course, I might have overlooked something ridiculously simple.

```
#define GLOP(operation) operation; if(!GFX::CheckError(#operation)) exit(1)
// GFX::CheckError() prints an error message, if any.

  GFX::Init(640, 480, 24, 0);
  GLOP(Texture2D::Enable());

  // shader setup
  GLuint  hFrag = GLOP(::glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER));
  GLuint  hVert = GLOP(::glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER));
  GLuint  hProg = GLOP(::glCreateProgram());

  std::ifstream inFile;
  ReadOpen("shader.frag", inFile);
  std::string  str(ReadFile(inFile));
  const char* pSource = str.c_str();
  GLOP(::glShaderSource(hFrag, 1, &pSource, 0));
  GLOP(::glCompileShader(hFrag));

  GLint logLength;
  glGetShaderiv(hFrag, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
  if (logLength > 0) {
      GLchar* log = (GLchar*)malloc(logLength);
      glGetShaderInfoLog(hFrag, logLength, &logLength, log);
      printf("Shader compile log:\n%s\n", log);
      free(log);
  }

  XR::ReadOpen(core.GetPath() + "shader.vert", inFile);
  XRLOG(XR::GetFileSize(inFile) << " bytes in file." << std::endl);
  str = XR::ReadFile(inFile);
  pSource = str.c_str();
  GLOP(::glShaderSource(hVert, 1, &pSource, 0));
  GLOP(::glCompileShader(hVert));

  glGetShaderiv(hVert, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
  if (logLength > 0) {
      GLchar* log = (GLchar*)malloc(logLength);
      glGetShaderInfoLog(hVert, logLength, &logLength, log);
      printf("Shader compile log:\n%s\n", log);
      free(log);
  }

  GLOP(::glAttachShader(hProg, hFrag));
  GLOP(::glAttachShader(hProg, hVert));
  GLOP(::glLinkProgram(hProg));

  glGetProgramiv(hProg, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
  if (logLength > 0) {
      GLchar* log = (GLchar*)malloc(logLength);
      glGetProgramInfoLog(hProg, logLength, &logLength, log);
      printf("Program link log:\n%s\n", log);
      free(log);
  }

  GLOP(::glUseProgram(hProg));

  // get uniform's location
  GLint locTex0 = GLOP(::glGetUniformLocation(hProg, "tex0"));

  /// [loading image, creating texture goes here. works perfectly.]

  while(core.IsRunning())
  {
    GLOP(::glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0));
    GLOP(pTex->Bind());
    GLOP(::glUniform1i(locTex0, GL_TEXTURE0));
    GLOP(::glPushMatrix());
    GLOP(::glTranslatef(GFX::GetFlopWidth() / 2, GFX::GetHeight() / 2, .0f)); // still no errors
    ::glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);  // crash
    ::glTexCoord2f(.0f, 1.0f);
    ::glVertex2f(-100.0f, -100.0f);
    ::glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    ::glVertex2f(100.0f, -100.0f);
    ::glTexCoord2f(1.0f, .0f);
    ::glVertex2f(100.0f, 100.0f);
    ::glTexCoord2f(.0f, .0f);
    ::glVertex2f(-100.0f, 100.0f);
    ::glEnd();
    ::glPopMatrix();
  }
```

Vertex shader:

```
void main( void )
{
  gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
  gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D tex0;

void  main()
{
  vec2  texCoords = gl_TexCoord[0].st;
  vec3  pixel = texture2D(tex0, texCoords).xyz;
  gl_FragColor = vec4(pixel, 1.0);
}
```

Output:

```
Successfully set video mode 640x480@24
Shader compile log:
Fragment shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Shader compile log:
Vertex shader was successfully compiled to run on hardware.

Program link log:
Vertex shader(s) linked, fragment shader(s) linked.
```

Answer (score 3):

Does it crash on the first frame?

I kind of doubt this has anything to do with your crash, but you should know that you're calling glVertex/glTexcoord in the wrong order. glVertex terminates a vertex, so in your case the first glVertex has no texcoord set, and your last texcoord gets applied the next loop through.

Comment: Yes, it crashes on the first frame. Thanks for pointing out the wrong order of glVertex2f and glTexCoord2f - it was a product of hastily writing out the textured quad rendering; I've edited it now. The runtime in this example never gets there before crashing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Immediate mode for submitting vertices like this isn't supported in the core profile, so I'm wondering if you're specifying the core profile when setting up your OpenGL context.  That would explain why it dies at glBegin.

Comment: Seems unlikely that would cause it to hard crash. Also he's got a call to glPushMatrix a few lines earlier which isn't core either.

Comment: Good point.  Also, I tried this on my own setup and it's fine to use a core profile with execute the commands.  They just don't do anything useful.  So I now think there's a problem elsewhere, possibly some kind of stack corruption caused by something else.